# PHP displaying images from an Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display images from an mySql databse with this code:

```
$con =mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
$sdb= mysql_select_db("d022cbde",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `images`";
$mq = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error with query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($mq) or die("Error in line 49");
$s=$row['photo'];
echo $row['photo'];

echo '<img src="'.$s.'" style="width:200px;height:200px">';
```

But instead of getting the image I just get this:

[image: Result image]

Does someone know the answer to this? All help is again welcome.

Comment: `mysql_*` in 2016...

Comment: recommended to NOT store images in the database

Comment: Please consider migrating from the `mysql_` functions (they were deprecated in PHP 5.5, which is so old that it no longer even receives security updates, and completely removed in PHP 7). Instead, use `mysqli_` functions or PDO.

Comment: What does `$s` contain? It looks like it should be a publicly-accessible URL to an image file, but I bet it's not. You might also inspect the missing image in your browser's development tools and also check its console and network tabs.

Comment: As Chris has said what does $s output? is it an image stored in the DB or is it a path to an image? if the later is the path correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please consider PDO as a better option.

```
#Connect to db
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=d022cbde', 'nonrootuser', 'pleaseusepasswords');

#Run query
  $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT photo FROM images");
  $sth->execute();

#Get the results of the query into an array, there could be more than one.
  $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

#Loop through results showing photos.
  foreach($result as $row) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row['photo'].'" style="width:200px;height:200px">';
  }
```

Now consider MVC instead of echoing if this is a larger project.

This example assumes that the "images" table has a "photo" column which is a URL to an image either a full path or relative path for the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

well your method worked, also, because of the questions: $s was the Data it gets from the Blob on mySQL. Now, I am happy all of you tried to help but I was browsing my Database as phpmyAdmin said this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7057433 bytes) in /www/phpmyadmin/PMA3/libraries/auth/signon.auth.lib.php on line 151
```

Now I can't connect to my Database orr view it or what so ever. I tried to delete the database and made a new one, but it didn't help... Do you know anything that could help or an different way of storing images online?

Comment: Somehow, after deleting and creating some Databases for infinite times it works again. thanks for the answer, PDO worked.